Как можно реализовать отправку писем на питоне без ошибки СПАМ?
Приложение отправляет письма, иногда все оотабатывает нормально, а иногда падает с ошибкой:
5.7.1 Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM;

Как можно пофиксить ее?
